# Author access to Sitecore Page Editor

Tags: sitecore

I'm attempting to set up an author role for a site I'm building. Let's call it `My Author`.

I've got the permissions mostly setup. `My Author` role can add/remove/edit the pages I want in the content tree. However, when opening a page in Page Editor, the role cannot edit any fields in the page.

I've made `My Author` role a member of these roles:

- Sitecore Client Authoring
- Sitecore Client Publishing
- Author
- Sitecore Client Designing

I'm at a loss as to what other role or specific permission I need to add.

UPDATE: If I remove the Sitecore Client Designing role, then the fields are editable in Page Editor. So it appears that that role is causing a deny on the editing capability. What I want is for My Authors to be able to do both. Any one know how I can accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that the fields on the page are outputted via the FieldRenderer? This is required to be able to edit the fields in the Page Editor.

https://sdn.sitecore.net/upload/sitecore7/70/page_editor_recommended_practices_for_developers_70-a4.pdf

Taken from page 6:

Sitecore controls for use in XSLT renderings and sublayouts, such as:

```
<sc:FieldRenderer FieldName="Text" runat="server" />
```

Sitecore provides specialized controls for Date, Text, Link, and Image fields:

```
<sc:Text Field="Text" runat="server" />
```

sc:field in XSLT renderings:

```
<xsl:value-of select="sc:field('Text')" />
```

The Sitecore MVC helper:

```
@Html.Sitecore().Field("Text")
```

Using the FieldRenderer.Render() method in code-behind:

```
FieldRenderer.Render("Text")
```

Comment: Along with this, you should double-check whether your user in the role has Write access to the item. An easy way to check this is by going to the Access Viewer application in Sitecore. (Don't forget to select a user to view in there, rather than a role, as users might have other roles as well which might take away access rights)

Comment: The Role can edit all fields via content editor, just not in Page Editor. Our site is MVC so, our fields that we want editable are rendered using this: @Html.Sitecore().Field("Label", Model.Item). When I'm logged in as admin I can edit all fields as desired in Page Editor.

Comment: I've checked the user's access and all the access looks correct and matches the My Author role.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I figure this out and the answer is unbelievable to me. When working on roles, I use two different browsers, FireFox for my admin login and IE11 for my Author role. One on one screen and one on the other, so I can tweak permissions on one and check on the other.

It appears that text editing in Page Editor is broken in IE11. I've also had many things not work in the latest version of Chrome as well.

I'm running Sitecore 7.5 which just came out, so this is very disappointing. Is there something I'm missing here? We have to use FireFox only? What happens when an auto FireFox update breaks something important? ugh.